# How Do I Reference Two MySQL Queries in Node.js/Express w/ EJS?

Tags: node.js

I'm having trouble passing the results of two MySQL queries to my templating engine (EJS). Here's a classic example how to do so with one query:

```
dbConn.query(sqlQuery, function (err, result) {
  if (err) throw err;    

  res.render('index', { 
    pageTitle: 'Index',
    pageID: 'index',
    qObj: result
    });
  });
```

It works like a charm. My index.ejs page receives qObj, and I can iterate the rows and display them as I see fit. But I want to pass two queries, like so:

```
res.render('index', { 
  pageTitle: 'Index',
  pageID: 'index',
  qObj1: result1,
  qObj2: result2
  });
```

But this won't work:

```
dbConn.query(sqlQuery1, function (err, result1) {
  if (err) throw err;    

  dbConn.query(sqlQuery2, function (err, result2) {
    if (err) throw err;    

    res.render('index', { 
      pageTitle: 'Index',
      pageID: 'index',
      qObj1: result1,
      qObj2: result2
      });

    });
  });
```

This either:

```
var qry1;
var qry2;

dbConn.query(sqlQuery1, function (err, result1) {
  if (err) throw err;    
  qry1 = Object.assign({}, result1);
  });

dbConn.query(sqlQuery2, function (err, result2) {
  if (err) throw err;    
  qry2 = Object.assign({}, result2);
  });

res.render('index', { 
  pageTitle: 'Index',
  pageID: 'index',
  qObj1: qry1,
  qObj2: qry2
  });
```

The objects don't persist after the dbConn.query() method is called. My attempt to make deep copies didn't work. Can anyone suggest a workaround? Thanks.

**Update**

Here's how I solved it. I removed instances of the following code:

```
if (err) throw err;
```

Leaving this:

```
dbConn.query(sql1, function (err, qry1) {
  dbConn.query(sql2, function (err, qry2) {   
    res.render('index', { 
      pageTitle: 'Index',
      pageID: 'index',
      qry1: qry1,
      qry2: qry2
      });
    });
  });
```

It'll do, but I sacrificed exception handling in order for it to work. It also seems weird to call an object method within the same object method call, at least in this case. I'll try the JSON option yBrodsky suggested, see if that helps.

Comment: the good old JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(yourOb))

Answer (score 0):

Solved. See explanation in **Update** section. Thanks for looking.